# getElement by nested tag name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get webpage link and nested tag's element:

```
<a href='/cacti/graph.php?action=view&amp;local_graph_id=279&amp;rra_id=all'><img class='graphimage' id='graph_279' src='/cacti/graph_image.php?local_graph_id=279&amp;rra_id=0&amp;view_type=tree&amp;graph_start=1482822537&amp;graph_end=1482908937' border='0' alt='ARD-Besat-MKT450G  - Bandwidth 16 Mb- ether3-Link to PTMP'></a>
```

This is part of my source code.

Finally I want:

```
cells(1,1).value="link address : /cacti/graph.php?action=view&amp;local_graph_id=279&amp;rra_id=all"

cells(1,2).value="image address: /cacti/graph_image.php?local_graph_id=279&amp;rra_id=0&amp;view_type=tree&amp;graph_start=1482822537&amp;graph_end=1482908937"

cells(1,3).value="image alt: ARD-Besat-MKT450G  - Bandwidth 16 Mb- ether3-Link to PTMP'
```

My function in VBA is:

```
Function WebPageLinks(internet, tagname As String)
Dim internetdata As HTMLDocument
Dim internetlink As Object
Dim internetinnerlink As Object
Set internetdata = internet.document
Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName(tagname)
For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets(1).Cells(linkcount, 1) = internetinnerlink.href' true
Sheets(1).Cells(linkcount, 2) = internetinnerlink.innerhtml' true
Sheets(1).Cells(linkcount, 3) =internetinnerlink.src ' error
Sheets(1).Cells(linkcount, 4) = internetinnerlink.alt' error
linkcount = linkcount + 1
Next internetinnerlink
End Function`
```

Comment: And what precisely is the question or problem?

Comment: i dont kow how to the element in innerhtml elements:(

Comment: It's only the 2 lines commented with error that is the issue? What is the intended result of those lines? Can you show example source code of the type of element you would use this on?

Comment: Finally i can solve by replacing:

Answer (score 0):

```
Function WebPageLinks2(internet, tagname As String, innerlinkcount)

Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim trObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim tdObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim flag As Boolean

flag = False

Set tr = internet.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each trObj In tr
    Set td = trObj.getElementsByClassName("graphimage")
    For Each tdObj In td
        'do something with each td object'
         If (InStr(CStr(tdObj.alt), "Agg") <> 0) Or (InStr(CStr(tdObj.alt), "ether1") <> 0) Or (InStr(CStr(tdObj.alt), "Ether1") <> 0) Then
             Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 7) = tdObj.src
             Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 6) = tdObj.alt
             'Debug.Print tdObj.alt
             'Debug.Print tdObj.src
             flag = True
             Call SaveGraphImageFromURLs(Sheets(5).Cells(17, 3).Value, Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 7).Value, _
             ToPathOfImages & "\" & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 1).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 3).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 6).Value & ".png", _
             Sheets(5).Cells(18, 3).Value, Sheets(5).Cells(19, 3).Value)
             Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Range("g" & innerlinkcount), hyperlinkAddress
             Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If InStr(trObj.href, "xport") And flag Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 5) = trObj.href
       flag = False
       Call SaveGraphImageFromURLs(Sheets(5).Cells(17, 3).Value, Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 5).Value, _
       Sheets(5).Cells(20, 3).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 1).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 3).Value & Sheets(1).Cells(innerlinkcount, 6).Value & ".csv", _
       Sheets(5).Cells(18, 3).Value, Sheets(5).Cells(19, 3).Value)
       Call csvimport((Sheets(5).Cells(20, 3).Value))
       Call tahlil(innerlinkcount)
       Call move_files(CStr((Sheets(5).Cells(20, 3).Value)), CStr(ToPath))
       'Debug.Print trObj.href
       'Debug.Print " \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
       Exit For
    End If
Next

root = root + 1

End Function
```